# How do I use jQuery to omit the "Select All" check box from the list of elements sent to the server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

When the "Select All" check box is used, it also sends that check box and it's value to the server. How do I remove or omit it from the node list before sending it to the server using jQuery?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [`remove`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) function:

```
$('#someId').remove();
```

However, it will not do anything if the user has Javascript disabled.

I highly recommend that you change the server-side code to ignore that checkbox.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way would be to not give it a name :)

```
<input type="checkbox" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(".checkbox :not[id=chkcheckAll]").each(function(){//what needs to be done});
```

Assuming the id for Check all checkbox is chkCheckAll.

HTH